# perl: What are PRO's and CON's with passing json on command line?

Tags: json, perl, command-line-arguments

I would like to standardize on using json as a data interchange format for various programming things I do? [ So far everything except MySQL :-( ]

The current question I have is:
*What are the PRO's and CON's of using a json format to pass arguments to a perl script via the command line?*

Here are some that I came up with.  PLEASE let me know if this is unworkable in the long term

**PRO:**

- Arguments can be in any order
- Arguments are passed in a standard format that can be used and parsed for other purposes. (passed to a javascript function, passed to PHP, saved in table)

**CON:**

- Don't know length limitation
- Don't know issues that may arise.

Here is what the command line would look like:

```
perl perlScript.pl {\"key\ 1\": \"value\ 1\", \"key\ 2\" : \"value\ 2\", \"key\ 3\" : 0  }
```

Here is what the script would look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Pass arguments to script on command line via json

use JSON;

# Use loop to combine all command line arguments into one variable
my $json = '';
foreach my $arg(@ARGV) {
  $json .= $arg;
}

# convert variable to hash
my $hash = decode_json($json);

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\%$hash);
```

Comment: CON: it is a quoting and backslashing nightmare

Comment: If you want complex data structures of this sort, you are running up against the difficulty of typing such things (and not making mistakes) on the command line.  Best to put your configuration options in a configuration file (which, yes, can be JSON).  Then use the argument parsing syntax of your platform.  Otherwise, people will find it uncomfortable to use your programs which have unusual behavior.

Comment: CON: you will be hunted down and severely chastised by irate users.

Comment: Arguments can be in any order with almost every argument parser, so that's not a plus for JSON.

Comment: @briandfoy: From my understanding command line arguments are passed and stored as an array not a hash and arrays are sequential so if the argument you are testing for is in $ARGV[0] instead of $ARGV[2] then the test will fail. 

@ DVK: Hmm..  I don't know, having all arguments needed stored as json and being able to send them to any process be it perl, PHP, javascript, etc, etc seems like a good idea.  Having to treat each process as a special case seems more of a headache.

@ mob: Doesn't the JSON module handle all of the quoting and backslashing why would you need to do it by hand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All your requirements/pros are met by the Getopt::Long module, with the following additional benefits

PROS of Getopt::Long

- It's a recognised best practice, and uses a syntax expected by other users of CLI tools
- It's self documenting for future development
- Provides default useful error messages in the event of typos, or wrong param types
- Many, many more...

The only PRO on json would be if there was an expectation that this would be provided as a web based API or tool, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Thats not to say JSON doesn't have a place in CLI tools, it is used extensively as a file based resource for configuration files, complex data storage, remote/external calls between software (RPC), as well providing a web front end.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check if we have this installed and look into it further.  Could the same structured line of arguments be used with other environments?  I'm trying to limit the 'specialness' needed with getting data into OR passing data between systems & languages. Sort of like: ` X = ( perl / php / javascript / sql / windows / linux / etc / etc / ???) ; arguments -> X -> output;`